# Refreshing my Android application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, refresh

Hi I want to refresh my android app. It weird all the time I get exceptions end my app keeps blowing up... Is it so difficult? Here goes my code:

```
public void refreshIt(long interv)
{
    thr = new Thread();
    try
    {
        thr.start();
        while(refreshing)
        {

            writeToMe("refresh....");//my method writing msgs to textview, don't mind it
            thr.sleep(1000);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){writeToMe(e.getMessage());}
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?  Why are you even thinking about this?  Forget about this code and please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There's all sorts of things that are wrong here but, whats your log cat

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh" ? anyway it seems like you're using [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) in your code. maybe consider [some](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) [other](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) [options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Why on earth would you update your UI from a background thread?

Comment: Talented programmers would log exceptions to LogCat to see the full stack trace of the exception. Talented developers who do not understand such a stack trace would post the stack trace as part of their question, pointing out where lines referenced in the stack trace are shown in the code listing.